# Where to find a list of iTunes Internet Radio Station URI's?

Tags: itunes

Looking for a source of iTunes Internet Radio Station URI's. Any suggestions?

Comment: URIs? You mean URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a source of radio stations that will play through iTunes, [SHOUTcast](http://www.shoutcast.com) is as good a starting point as any. Go for the .M3U streams, these will open and play in iTunes.

Comment: Appreciate the reference to SHOUTcast. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any .M3U streams on this site.

Comment: Just click on the "download" icon next to the stream you want to listen to, and you will be presented with three stream options - M3U is in the middle. Just click on M3U and it should open in iTunes - Firefox will initially ask you which application to open it with, iTunes should be the default helper app (I've not tried this with Safari...) ;-)